# Lazy Loading for multiple series unlike multiple points in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I found one good example of lazy loading

```
 function afterSetExtremes(e) {

        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

        chart.showLoading('Loading data from server...');
        $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/from-sql.php?start=' + Math.round(e.min) +
                '&end=' + Math.round(e.max) + '&callback=?', function (data) {
                alert(data);
                chart.series[0].setData(data);
                chart.hideLoading();
            });
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/lazy-loading/

But it works only for one series with multiple points but i have multiseries data.

**Link for json file:**  http://www.filedropper.com/data_5

How the above code can be used for multiseries data?

Comment: Did you find a solution? If yes, could you please post it here?

Answer (score 0):

In the lazy-loading example we use single serie, but you can extend that to use with more of them. Only what you need is prepare source of data (like JSON, in our case is http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/from-sql.php) which returns array of (in your scenario) 6 series. Next step is declare 6 series in series array (chart configuration, line 86). Last step is edit `afterSetExtremes` event and add update all series, instead of single (line 13 in demo).

Ref:
- http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/lazy-loading/

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but with a series of volumes in a separate chart. I did all your steps, but it didn't work for me. First I split the JSON data set into ohlc and volume, then declared several series and then I updated `afterSetExtremes` like this `chart.series[0].setData(ohlc);`, `chart.series[1].setData(volume);`, etc... Is this the right approach?